# How should I google git's .. syntax?

Tags: google-search

I'd like to look up the documentation for Git's `..` syntax which is used, for example, in a command like `git log master..` that lists the commits in my branch and not in master. I'd like to know how they word the documentation so that I can explain it accurately and succinctly to colleagues.

Here are the searches I have tried

- .. [[google](https://www.google.com/webhp?#safe=active&q=..)][[bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=..&go=Submit&pq=..)]
- .. git [[google](https://www.google.com/webhp#safe=active&q=..+git)][[bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=..+git&go=Submit&qs=n&pq=..+git)]
- ".." git [[google](https://www.google.com/webhp#safe=active&q=%22..%22+git)][[bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%22..%22+git&go=Submit&qs=n&pq=%22..%22+git)]
- ".." site:git-scm.com [[google](https://www.google.com/webhp#safe=active&q=%22..%22+site:git-scm.com)][[bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%22..%22+site%3Agit-scm.com&go=Submit&qs=n&pq=%22..%22+site%3Agit-scm.com)]

The results are all pretty bad. Is there a better way to search for documentation on language specific use of punctuation syntax like Git's `..`?

Comment: Try at http://symbolhound.com/

Comment: @Jonno Unfortunately searching symbolhound for "git .." doesn't really throw up useful results. Googling for "git dot" is more useful. Googling "git double dot" is even better ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I'd like to look up the documentation for Git's `..` syntax

> which is used, for example, in a command like `git log master..`

They are called **Double Dot** `..` and **Triple Dot** `...` Range Specifications.

You also see them referred to as **Range Syntax** or **Dot Syntax**.

Searching http://www.google.com for any of these terms will return useful results.

---

#### Short Summary

> **git log A..B (two dots)**
>
> While this syntax looks like a "range" of commits from A to B, it is
>   actually a short hand for `git log ^A B`:
>
> - show all commits reachable from B; B itself is included
> - excluding those reachable from A; A itself is excluded
>
> So given the following history (with the oldest commits on the left,
>   the newest on the right):
>
> ```
> *--*--*--A--*--*--*--B
> ```
>
> `git log A..B` will show all the commits to the right of A.
>
> Note that `git log A..` is equivalent to `git log A..HEAD`.
>
> **git log A...B (three dots)**
>
> The git-rev-list man page describes this as a special notation for
>   "symmetric difference".
>
> It is equivalent to `git log A B --not $(git merge-base --all A B)`.
>
> In plain English, this means "all commits that are reachable from
>   either A or B but not from both.

Source [Git "range" or "dot" syntax](https://wincent.com/wiki/Git_%22range%22_or_%22dot%22_syntax)

---

#### Detailed Summary

> **Double Dot**
>
> The most common range specification is the double-dot syntax. This
>   basically asks Git to resolve a range of commits that are reachable
>   from one commit but aren’t reachable from another. For example, say
>   you have a commit history that looks like:
>
> [image]
>
> You want to see what is in your experiment branch that hasn’t yet been
>   merged into your master branch. You can ask Git to show you a log of
>   just those commits with master..experiment – that means “all commits
>   reachable by experiment that aren’t reachable by master.” For the sake
>   of brevity and clarity in these examples, I’ll use the letters of the
>   commit objects from the diagram in place of the actual log output in
>   the order that they would display:
>
> ```
> $ git log master..experiment
> D
> C
> ```
>
> If, on the other hand, you want to see the opposite – all commits in
>   master that aren’t in experiment – you can reverse the branch names.
>   experiment..master shows you everything in master not reachable from
>   experiment:
>
> ```
> $ git log experiment..master
> F
> E
> ```
>
> This is useful if you want to keep the experiment branch up to date
>   and preview what you’re about to merge in. Another very frequent use
>   of this syntax is to see what you’re about to push to a remote:
>
> ```
> $ git log origin/master..HEAD
> ```
>
> This command shows you any commits in your current branch that aren’t
>   in the master branch on your origin remote. If you run a git push and
>   your current branch is tracking origin/master, the commits listed by
>   git log origin/master..HEAD are the commits that will be transferred
>   to the server. You can also leave off one side of the syntax to have
>   Git assume HEAD. For example, you can get the same results as in the
>   previous example by typing git log origin/master.. – Git substitutes
>   HEAD if one side is missing.
>
> **Multiple Points**
>
> The double-dot syntax is useful as a shorthand; but perhaps you want
>   to specify more than two branches to indicate your revision, such as
>   seeing what commits are in any of several branches that aren’t in the
>   branch you’re currently on. Git allows you to do this by using either
>   the ^ character or --not before any reference from which you don’t
>   want to see reachable commits. Thus these three commands are
>   equivalent:
>
> ```
> $ git log refA..refB
> $ git log ^refA refB
> $ git log refB --not refA
> ```
>
> This is nice because with this syntax you can specify more than two
>   references in your query, which you cannot do with the double-dot
>   syntax. For instance, if you want to see all commits that are
>   reachable from refA or refB but not from refC, you can type one of
>   these:
>
> ```
> $ git log refA refB ^refC
> $ git log refA refB --not refC
> ```
>
> This makes for a very powerful revision query system that should help
>   you figure out what is in your branches.
>
> **Triple Dot**
>
> The last major range-selection syntax is the triple-dot syntax, which
>   specifies all the commits that are reachable by either of two
>   references but not by both of them. Look back at the example commit
>   history in:
>
> [image]
>
> If you want to see what is in master or experiment but not any common
>   references, you can run
>
> ```
> $ git log master...experiment
> F
> E
> D
> C
> ```
>
> Again, this gives you normal log output but shows you only the commit
>   information for those four commits, appearing in the traditional
>   commit date ordering.
>
> A common switch to use with the log command in this case is
>   --left-right, which shows you which side of the range each commit is in. This helps make the data more useful:
>
> ```
> $ git log --left-right master...experiment
> < F
> < E
> > D
> > C
> ```
>
> With these tools, you can much more easily let Git know what commit or commits you want to inspect.

Source [Git Tools - Revision Selection](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection)

Comment: Thanks - I guess the tricky bit becomes how to use Google to find out what they are called (in order to use that name in Google to discover how they are used).